# Listing all applications that are actively listening through audio inputs

Tags: macos, terminal, audio, security, microphone

I would like to know if there is any way to use terminal to list all active applications that are listening to audio devices (built in microphones, usb mics, etc) via terminal. I already know about external programs ([OverSight](https://objective-see.com/products/oversight.html)), but I want to know specifically if there is any way for this do be done through the command line. I know that this is possible, because applications similar to OverSight are able to monitor and give real-time information regarding audio usage.

Comment: *I know that this is possible, because applications similar to OverSight are able to monitor and give real-time information regarding audio usage.*  Would you care to share these programs so we're not duplicating work?  Please remember, we're not aware of what you've already tried and where things did/didn't work.  Details are key to getting you a useful answer.

Comment: Looks like OverSight [uses](https://github.com/objective-see/OverSight/blob/f5045aa3831e3c9a5f8386066039be1140f2e69d/Application/Application/AVMonitor.m#L1007)  this, [`AudioObjectAddPropertyListenerBlock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudio/1422686-audioobjectaddpropertylistenerbl), to subscribe to the relevant events emitted by the `coreaudio` process.

Comment: Edit: just kidding, that looks like it only emits events related to input device changes, not applications listening on each device. Looks like they [actually just parse logs](https://github.com/objective-see/OverSight/blob/f5045aa3831e3c9a5f8386066039be1140f2e69d/Application/Application/AVMonitor.m#L561) `process == 'coreaudiod' && subsystem == 'com.apple.TCC' && category == 'access'`, with a regex no less. Ugly but works. Should be doable via CLI though…

Comment: Check out https://superuser.com/a/1277723

Answer (score 0):

Closest I can do for tonight is (using `ggrep` from `brew install coreutils`) getting `pid`s of processes requesting the microphone (which [appears to be how OverSight does it](https://github.com/objective-see/OverSight/blob/f5045aa3831e3c9a5f8386066039be1140f2e69d/Application/Application/AVMonitor.m#L561)):

```bash
log show \
 --info \
 --predicate \
 "process == 'coreaudiod' && category == 'access'" |
 grep kTCCServiceMicrophone |
 ggrep -o -P 'pid\:\K[0-9]+'
```

This will return something like

```
82931
83353
83496
83856
83856
```

Unfortunately, it's not clear how to get process names/ paths; the obvious `ps -p <pid>` yields nothing. They use [some arcane](https://github.com/objective-see/OverSight/blob/f5045aa3831e3c9a5f8386066039be1140f2e69d/Shared/Utilities.m#L663-L719) method in OverSight to apparently work around this, but I'm unable to divine how to do this via CLI.